# Creating website with www.xyz.com sitename on azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create a webapp on Azure with www.xyz.com, but getting only option of .azurewebsites.net while trying to create a webapp on azure.

Can you some help me how to change .azurewebsites.net to .com?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below are the Steps to configure custom domains to your azure app service

- Create A record with Azure App Service IP address (you can get IP address from Custom Domains section or use PowerShell cmdlet) in your DNS management tool (ex: godaddy, cloudflare,...)
- Create TXT record with azure App Service domain name (ex: {AppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net in your DNS Management tool.
- Follow the above steps for additional sub domains (ex: www)
- Add Host Name under Custom Domain section of your App Service or use below PowerShell cmdlet:

```
Set-AzureRmWebApp -Name {AppServiceName}
  -ResourceGroupName {ResourceGroupName}
  -HostNames @(www.xyz.com, {AppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net")
```

Comment: Thank you! Shall I create a site with appname.azurewebsites.net first?

Comment: Also when it will be shown as .com site on azure? Will it automatically convert the [AppServiceName}.azurewebsites.net to .com?

Comment: If you create app service with name "xyz" in azure, The following hostname will be created for you in azure xyz.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score -3):

You need to map an exisitng custom DNS name to your Azure Web App.

For more details, refer "[Map an exisitng custom DNS name to Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain)".

Detailed workaround steps are mentioned here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/85d683cc-b5db-4808-8922-6f0abcae1e3b/hostname-not-adding?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin 

I have added detailed steps.

Comment: @PRADEEPCHEEKATLA - the steps need to be added *here*, in the answer. Not on an external site. Otherwise, it's still a link-only answer.